# How can I find the delay between two signals?

Tags: matlab, time-series, delay, neural-network

I am using NARX in Matlab.

Is there any method to find the delay between input and output signals?

My aim is to decrease memory length by finding the delay.

TIA.

Comment: Hi, to my mind you should compute the groupdelay introduced by your filter ("your Neural Network"). Guessing that your NN just work as an IIR of FIR filter...  

As you are working with matlab i suggest you to look at this document : 
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/compensate-for-delay-and-distortion-introduced-by-filters.html#:~:text=Filtering%20a%20signal%20introduces%20a,frequency%20components%20more%20than%20others.

Comment: no. I have an input signal and an output signal. There is a delay between them. How can I find that delay?